# Setting up COBOL Compiler under Mac OS?

Tags: macos, cobol, toolchain

In my university, we're being taught COBOL, and I'm trying to get a head start and learn COBOL, C++, and Java before I get into the classes next year.
Problem is; COBOL is *so* old, it's hard to grab support for it in mac (my laptop is a mac). I understand it runs fine on Mac, but finding someone who can explain how to set up the compiler is another story.

Comment: Hi, Jonathan: welcome to Academia.SE. Unfortunately, this is a CS question, not a question about academia. This is probably a better fit for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), so I will migrate it there.

Comment: @aeismail Tools questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow not Programmers.

Comment: ...And welcome to StackOverflow! I understand there's some modern dialects of COBOL you might be able to try (including, I believe, a COBOL.NET). failing that you might want to try emulation (legality may vary, check you local laws.)

Answer (score 23):

You can use `brew` to install GNU Cobol (Open Cobol). Just type:

```
brew install gnu-cobol
```

Then to compile program use:

```
cobc -x hello.cob
```

Browse `--help` for more option (like super nice `-free`)

Comment: Awesome, worked perfect for me on Mac OS X 10.11 Sierra.

Comment: Works on macOS Mojave, too

Answer (score 4):

Is there a particular Cobol you are trying to use. If not try

- [Open Cobol](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/)

There are some very old notes for the mac [here](http://www.opencobol.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=968&forum=1) but you might be better off asking a question in the [Open Cobol Help forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/109660/).

The Open-Cobol project are currently collecting sample cobol programs which might be useful to you.

Comment: The install instructions for Linux/Unix will work on a mac if you approach if from a terminal window.