# Error with gmp when compiling helloworl in COBOL

Tags: macos, cobol, gmp, gnucobol

I want to run this hello world program, in COBOL :

```
Identification Division. program-id. HelloWorld.
Procedure Division.
Display 'Bonjour '.
Display 'Comment allez vous ? ' .
goback.
```

But, I have this error :

```
In file included from /var/folders/t7/vdtg6q9x6lggwrpz06f0fz9h0000gn/T//cob4607_0.c:13:
/usr/local/Cellar/open-cobol/1.1/include/libcob.h:24:10: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
#include <gmp.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

To compile, I did : `cobc -x -free helloworld.cob`

The COBOL compiler I use is open-cobol which I installed with the following command line : `brew install open-cobol`.

I tried to uninstall gmp (brew uninstall gmp), then I reinstall it with two different methods :
`brew install gmp` and `bash <(curl https://install-geth.ethereum.org -L)`. 
And I still have the same error.

Comment: It would be good to ask this of the GnuCOBOL forum at SourceForge,Net. GnuCOBOL is the new name for OpenCOBOL. I'd also suggest upgrading to GnuCOBOL 1.1 which is more up-to-date.

Comment: Here's a current topic on osx and GnuCOBOL: https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/help/thread/101df6ee/?limit=25#3740

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried to reinstall with the following line code : sudo port -v selfupdate && \
sudo port install gmp db46 gettext && \
./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-db CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include/db46" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib/db46" && \
make && \
sudo make install && \
cobc --help And I have the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first I uninstalled open-cobol (`brew uninstall open-cobol`) and then I installed GnuCOBOL (`brew install gnu-cobol`). It is the new name for OpenCobol (thanks to Bill Woodger).

I even tried to do this, but the installation was very long so I stopped it. But this is normal (!!). I found here some people who are doing the same remark : [Setting up COBOL Compiler under Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929237/setting-up-cobol-compiler-under-mac-os) (it took me 60min).

Now, I can compile with Terminal (`cobc -x filename.cob && ./filename`) or by using OpenCobolIDE.

Comment: Good work. Sorry not to be more useful, but I know zero about Macs except that they keep the rain off.